# mockResolvedValue returns undefined

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

I want to test the function below using the tests below. However, I fail in mocking the userService.login function, which always returns undefined instead of desired value. I have tried these approaches https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mock-return-values (please see the tests), but nothing seems to work.

FUNCTION

```
    static async login(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> {
        const userDTO = req.body;
        try {
            const accessToken = await userService.login(userDTO);
           // accessToken is undefined here :(

            res.setHeader('authorisation', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
            res.send('Logged in');
        } catch (e) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line callback-return
            next(e);
        }
    }
```

TESTS:

```
import UserService from '@services/users.service';
import UserController from '@routers/controller/users.controller';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import UserRepository from '@data-access/user.repository';

jest.mock('@services/users.service');

let userService: UserService;
const fakeToken = 's$sdfDgf45d';

beforeAll(() => {
    userService = new UserService(UserRepository);
    // userService.login = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('s$sdfDgf45d').mockRejectedValue('error');
});


describe('UserController: ', () => {
    const mockReq = {
        body: {
            login: 'Artyom',
            password: 'qwerty123'
        }
    };
    const mockRes = {
        setHeader: jest.fn(),
        send: jest.fn()
    };
    const nextFunction = jest.fn();

    test('the  class constructor should have been called', () => {
        expect(UserService).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    test('should send auth token in case of success scenario', async () => {
        // @ts-ignore
        userService.login.mockResolvedValue('s$sdfDgf45d').mockRejectedValue('error');
        // jest.spyOn(userService, 'login').mockResolvedValue('s$sdfDgf45d' as any).mockRejectedValue('error');
        await UserController.login(mockReq as Request, mockRes as any as Response, nextFunction as NextFunction);
// that's the test that fails
        expect(mockRes.setHeader.mock.calls[0]).toEqual(['authorisation', `Bearer ${fakeToken}`]);
        expect(mockRes.send.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual('Logged in');
    });

    test('should throw an error', async () => {
        return expect((userService.login as jest.Mock)()).rejects.toMatch('error');
    });
});
```

ERROR:

```
      Array [
        "authorisation",
    -   "Bearer s$sdfDgf45d",
    +   "Bearer undefined",
```

CODE:

https://github.com/lion9/node-express

Comment: What are you actually testing here? Where does the service used in UserController's static method come from, how does that relate to the mock in the tests? And if you're mocking the service why also create an *instance* of it with the UserRepository *class*?

Comment: https://github.com/lion9/node-express please feel free to have a look at the entire project. https://github.com/lion9/node-express/blob/master/src/routers/controller/users.controller.ts - the login function (first from the above) is the one being tested

Comment: No, please put a [mre] in the question rather than expecting people to trawl through a repo.

Comment: the repo now contains a minimal set of files to run 'npm run test-watch' I am not sure how I can create a sandboxed snippet w/ Jest support

Comment: I didn't suggest a stack snippet, they're for client code. But fundamentally it's unclear from your tests what you think you're actually testing - one of them asserts on a test double that's not actually connected to the code under test, another *exercises only the test double*. In general I wouldn't recommend unit testing a controller anyway; as you see it ends up being very coupled to the Express API, which you don't own. You also appear not to be hashing the password.

Comment: It's a training task. I am supposed to test exactly controller's methods and not to hash password. I also tried to create a repl https://replit.com/talk/share/Jest-sample/131876